# Node.js and MongoDB: aggregate returning object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, aggregate

I am running the Node.js + MongDB exercice proposed at https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_join.asp

There are two collections, **orders** and **products**. After the **aggregate**, the expected result should be:

```
[
  { _id: 1, product_id: 154, status: 1, orderdetails: [
    { _id: 154, name: 'Chocolate Heaven' } ]
  }
]
```

However, in my local instance, I am getting the following result:

```
[ { _id: 1, product_id: 154, status: 1, orderdetails: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

What shoud I do in order to get an **{ _id: 154, name: 'Chocolate Heaven'}** instead of an **[Object]**?

Comment: If you are seeing this with console.log try logging with `console.log(JSON.stringify(returnedDataHere));`

Comment: Use console.dir instead of console.log on variables with nested objects and arrays if you want to display them in full in the console.